# Python replace spaces in string iteratively

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to replace spaces with hyphens one at a time in each possible position in python. For example `the man said hi` should produce a list of all the possible hyphen positions, including multiple hyphens:

```
the-man said hi
the man-said hi
the man said-hi 
the-man said-hi
the-man-said hi
the man-said-hi
the-man-said-hi
```

The length of the strings varies in number of spaces, so it can't be a fix for just 3 spaces. I've been experimenting with `re.search` and `re.sub` in a while loop, but haven't found a nice way yet.

Comment: so what you try , yourself ?

Comment: Are you determined to use regex?  And how effecient are you looking to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to produce all space-and-dash combinations, then recombine your string with those:

```
from itertools import product

def dashed_combos(inputstring):
    words = inputstring.split()
    for combo in product(' -', repeat=len(words) - 1):
        yield ''.join(w for pair in zip(words, combo + ('',)) for w in pair)
```

The last line zips the words together with the dashes and spaces (adding in an empty string at the end to make up the pairs), then flattens that and joins them into a single string.

Demo:

```
>>> for combo in dashed_combos('the man said hi'):
...     print combo
... 
the man said hi
the man said-hi
the man-said hi
the man-said-hi
the-man said hi
the-man said-hi
the-man-said hi
the-man-said-hi
```

You can always skip the first iteration of that loop (with only spaces) with [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import product, islice

def dashed_combos(inputstring):
    words = inputstring.split()
    for combo in islice(product(' -', repeat=len(words) - 1), 1, None):
        yield ''.join(w for pair in zip(words, combo + ('',)) for w in pair)
```

All this is extremely memory efficient; you can easily handle inputs with hundreds of words, provided you don't try and store all possible combinations in memory at once.

Slightly longer demo:

```
>>> for combo in islice(dashed_combos('the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'), 10):
...     print combo
... 
the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy-dog
the quick brown fox jumped over the-lazy dog
the quick brown fox jumped over the-lazy-dog
the quick brown fox jumped over-the lazy dog
the quick brown fox jumped over-the lazy-dog
the quick brown fox jumped over-the-lazy dog
the quick brown fox jumped over-the-lazy-dog
the quick brown fox jumped-over the lazy dog
the quick brown fox jumped-over the lazy-dog
the quick brown fox jumped-over the-lazy dog
>>> for combo in islice(dashed_combos('the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'), 200, 210):
...     print combo
... 
the-quick-brown fox jumped-over the lazy-dog
the-quick-brown fox jumped-over the-lazy dog
the-quick-brown fox jumped-over the-lazy-dog
the-quick-brown fox jumped-over-the lazy dog
the-quick-brown fox jumped-over-the lazy-dog
the-quick-brown fox jumped-over-the-lazy dog
the-quick-brown fox jumped-over-the-lazy-dog
the-quick-brown fox-jumped over the lazy dog
the-quick-brown fox-jumped over the lazy-dog
the-quick-brown fox-jumped over the-lazy dog
```

Comment: Excellent. Cheers! Amazing the breadth of modules out there!